# how when loading a page to click on a button in react?

Tags: reactjs

how when loading a page to click on a button in react?

I need a button to be pressed when the page loads

https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-poitras-3sknp

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={() => alert("loaded")}>button</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to alert upon page load?

Comment: yes, like onLoad method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) to save a reference to the `button` element combined with [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to detect when the component mounts

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function App() {
  const buttonRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    buttonRef.current.click();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button ref={buttonRef} onClick={() => alert("button")}>
        button
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I need her to press a button when loading a page

Comment: @recile like this ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this. Button clicks happens on page load and also when clicked on button?

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.buttonClicked = this.buttonClicked.bind(this);
  }
  
  componentDidMount(){
    this.buttonClicked();
  }
  
  buttonClicked(){
    alert("I'm Clicked");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={() => this.buttonClicked()}>
        button
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

From [React's Hooks API Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

> The function passed to useEffect will run after the render is committed to the screen.

So you can always consider to use useEffect to run whatever side effects do you want right after the page rendered. Make sure to pass `[]` as the second argument to make sure the arrow function will only be called once.

This is an alternative example of using the useEffect hook with  `document.getElementById(id)` instead of `useRef` since that has already been mentioned

It is still better to use `useRef` especially if the component will be reusable in the same page.

```js
import React, {useEffect} from "react";

useEffect(() => {
  document.getElementById("btn").click();
},[]);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button id="btn" onClick={() => alert("loaded")}>button</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```